# stuff() adds separator even when fields are empty

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please consider the following statement:

```
select stuff((
           select '; ' + ([FIELD_1] + [FIELD_2] + [...] + [FIELD_N])
           from   [TABLE] t1
           where  t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
           for    xml path ('')
        ),1,1, '')
from    [TABLE] t2
```

If the statement concatenates 10 records with the same `ID` but all records have no value ('', or empty, instead of `null`), the output is:

```
; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ; ;
```

If 2 records are filled, I end up with

```
; ; ; AAA; ; ; ; BBB;
```

What I would want in these 2 cases is `null`, respectively `AAA; BBB`

I tried fixing it like this:

```
select stuff((
           select case when [FIELD_1] <> '' then '; ' + ([FIELD_1]) else '' end
           from   [TABLE] t1
           where  t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
           for    xml path ('')
        ),1,1, '')
from    [TABLE] t2
```

This works, and is elegantly enough for me when I'm only selecting `FIELD_1`. But when I'm selecting many concatinated fields (`FIELD_1 + ... + FIELD_N`), this becomes quite ugly fast.

What am I doing wrong? Isn't `stuff()` supposed to take care of my problem as a function?

Comment: `';' + '' ` will gives you `';'` . this is correct. If you want to skip empty string, add that condition to the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a condition to the `WHERE` clause to exclude rows with all value empty string

```
select stuff((
           select '; ' + ([FIELD_1] + [FIELD_2] + [...] + [FIELD_N])
           from   [TABLE] t1
           where  t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
           and    [FIELD_1] + [FIELD_2] + [...] + [FIELD_N] <> ''
           for    xml path ('')
        ),1,1, '')
from    [TABLE] t2
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is not intended to show a better way to do the query - it is intended to explain the query you are using.

To solve your problem you should use the where clause as squirrel demonstrated in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52775734/3094533), instead of using the `case` expression. No point of selecting things you have no use for.

I see a lot of confusion about this method of string aggregation - too many people are using it without understanding what each part of it does - so here is a simple explanation:

There are three parts to this technique:

1. aggregate the values in the columns. That's what the `FOR XML PATH('')` does.
   The `FOR XML PATH('')` will return an xml string where the xml tags are the 
   column name (or aliases) of the query. (see `cte_ForXml` and `Aggregated` 
   column in the sample script below).
2. Add a delimiter between the values. That's what the `';' +` does.
   It also removes the column name XML tags from the results - 
   by changing the column name to an empty string. Empty aliases are invalid in 
   T-SQL, but by concatenating another value to the column the column name can 
   no longer be used.
   See `cte_ForXml_WithAnEmptyString` and `OnlyValuesAggregated` on the sample 
   script.
3. Remove the extra delimiter at the beginning of the string. That's what the 
   `stuff` does.
   See `cte_FirstDlimiterRemoved` and `FullQuery` in the sample script.

What `stuff` does is to insert a string into another string, at a specified `index`, while removing `length` charecters from the original string. If you are inserting an empty string, you are simply removing the part specified by the `index` and `length` parameters from the original string.

**Sample script** to illustrate the different steps of this string aggregation technique:

```
DECLARE @String_Agg AS TABLE 
(
    s varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @String_Agg (s) VALUES
('1'), ('2'), ('3')

;WITH cte_ForXml(Aggregated) AS
(
    SELECT s
    FROM @String_Agg
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
, cte_ForXml_WithAnEmptyString(OnlyValuesAggregated) AS
(
    SELECT '' + s
    FROM @String_Agg
    FOR XML PATH('')
) 
, cte_ForXmlWithADelimiter(AggregatedWithADlimiter) AS
(
    SELECT ';' + s
    FROM @String_Agg
    FOR XML PATH('')
), cte_FirstDlimiterRemoved(FullQuery) AS
(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ';' + s
            FROM @String_Agg
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, ''
    )
)

SELECT Aggregated,  OnlyValuesAggregated, AggregatedWithADlimiter, FullQuery
FROM cte_ForXml
CROSS JOIN cte_ForXml_WithAnEmptyString
CROSS JOIN cte_ForXmlWithADelimiter
CROSS JOIN cte_FirstDlimiterRemoved
```

Results:

```
Aggregated                  OnlyValuesAggregated    AggregatedWithADlimiter     FullQuery
<s>1</s><s>2</s><s>3</s>    123                     ;1;2;3                      1;2;3
```

Comment: Exactly. `stuff()` is a convenient way of doing that. An alternate method is to use `substring()` with `len()`

Comment: The problem with `substring` and `len` is that you need the actual string twice - meaning either put the value of the `for xml` query into a variable, or repeat the entire query - both ways are too cumbersome compared to simply using `stuff`.