# SQL 'Stuff' to concatenate add 2 spaces - Rextester demo attached

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a scenario where I concatenate 3 strings together. The length of each string is 25 and so when I concatenate I want the strings to have fixed width.

Desired output format:

```
**String1(length 22 + 3spaces)String2(length 9 +16 spaces)String3(length8+17spaces)**
```

Current output:

```
****String1(length 22 + 3spaces)**2 additional spaces**String2(length 9 +16 spaces)**2 additional spaces**String3(length8+17spaces)**2 additional spaces**
```

I don't want the additional spaces to show up. Is there a way to do this?

https://rextester.com/GSWML31014

Attached rextester demo here. Any help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a string of 25 chars before you concatenate

```
SELECT (
           SELECT LEFT(t1.testdata + SPACE(25), 25)
           FROM   #temp1 t1
           FOR    XML PATH ('')
       ) AS TheOutput
```

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate this query with space(75)? Pls chk my rextester demo

Comment: @Rick What do you mean can't you just replace the `25` with `75`?

Comment: what is the purpose of concatenate with space(75) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply cast them to `char(25)` - SQL Server will add as many trailing white spaces as needed - You don't need the `stuff` because you don't have a delimiter to remove from the beginning of the result.

You don't even need to concatenate an empty string because once you've used `cast`, the column have no alias and so `for xml path('')` will simply concatenate the values. For more information, [see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775632/stuff-adds-separator-even-when-fields-are-empty/52775736#52775736)

```
SELECT CAST(cid AS CHAR(25))
FROM #temp1
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Result: `'1001                     1001                     1001                     '` (added `'` to show the length of the string)